# Prestashop theme doesn't work

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I bought this [theme](http://demo.snstheme.com/presta/sns-nova/en/)
My prestashop version is 1.6 and and version of theme is 1.5
When I've been install their prestashop everything is ok but when I've been use theme it doesn't work, it's work like this image (doesn't add css files)
[image: using presta 1.6 and theme is 1.5]

Comment: Check browser console errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't install modules and now is right